# How do I call a method that reads the text file created in a separate method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here are the instructions:

Exercise 2
Write a program in a single file that:

Main:

Creates 10 random doubles, all between 1 and 11,

Calls a method that writes 10 random doubles to a text file, one number per line.

Calls a method that reads the text file and displays all the doubles and their sum accurate to two decimal places.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

10.6269119604172
2.737790338909455
5.427925738865128
1.3742058065472509
1.1858700262498836
4.180391276485228
4.910969998930675
5.710858234343958
7.790857007373052
3.1806714736219543

The total is 47.13

I have it all written but nothing is coming out on the txt file. I need help with the second method because I think I need to change something but I'm not sure what.

```
public class Program2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] nums = new double[10];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = 1 + Math.random() * 11;   
        }
    
        printNum(nums);
        
        sumNum(nums);

    }
    
    public static void printNum(double[] values) {
        
        try {
            
        
        java.io.File randomNums = new java.io.File("Project1.txt");
        randomNums.createNewFile();
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(randomNums);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            output.println(i);
        }
        
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("EX");
        }
        
        
        }
    
    public static void sumNum(double[] ints) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner("Project1.txt");
        double sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
             sum = sum + i;
            
        }
        System.out.printf("\n%-.2f", "The total is ", sum);
        
        input.close();
        
        
    }
        
        
        

    
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%f The total is ", sum);`

Comment: @Abigail Curtis: Are you using an IDE (Visual Studio Code, IntelliJ, Eclipse)? If so, use it to keep your Java code formatted properly. Properly formatted makes it easier for you to understand your own code. Also, use a debugger to step through code when it doesn't produce the results you expect. Placing a breakpoint on the line ```sum = sum + i;``` most likely would have helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Method printNum

There are two reasons why you may see no output in the file: Some error occurred or the file is not flushed/closed by the time you read from it.

Be sure to flush and close the PrintWriter before leaving the method:

```
output.flush();
output.close();
```

In case some error occurs, you just print `EX`, hiding what is actually going on. So use this catch block:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.print("EX");
    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Read what the program is trying to tell you.

And last but not least: You are not printing the random numbers but the loop count. Use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    output.println(values[i]);
}
```

### Method sumNum

You need to open the file for reading. Your line does not do it:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("Project1.txt");
```

Use this instead:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Project1.txt"));
```

Next, you are not reading from the scanner. Inside your loop use

```
sum = sum + input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine();
```

Finally you need to print the result, as mentioned by OldProgrammer:

```
System.out.printf("The total is %f", sum);
```

### Main method

The random numbers you generate are not in the defined range. You can figure this out.

Comment: It helped, but now it wants me to change sum to "string" but when I do that it messes everything up.

Comment: Who is it? What is the exact error message? On which line does it occur?
But I found some more things and edited my answer.

Comment: Isn't ```System.out.printf("The total is %.2f\n", sum);``` more readable?